Printf inside the qemu device typeinfo file(similar to edu.c), where can I find the output?
qemu version: 9.0.3, qemu-system-x86_64
device type: pcie device, edit based on the edu.c
print function: printf
qemu configuration:
./configure --prefix=$PWD/../qemu_release --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-debug --enable-sdl --enable-kvm --enable-tools --disable-curl --enable-slirp
start shell:
sudo ./bin/qemu-system-x86_64 
-m 4G 
-smp 2 
-kernel ../bzImage 
-drive file=../rootfs.img,format=raw 
-append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0 rw noapic" 
-net nic,model=e1000 
-net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no 
-nographic 
-device my_pcie\

qemu -monitor not found the output;
When the device driver is invoked, no output is seen in the console;
because is a virtual device in qemu, printk is not appropriate;

excepting:
Find the output of printf function, or is there any other way to debug the typeinfo file of the device.
Any help would be appreciated.
